# unable to run API controller with dbcontext injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-apicontroller

i get following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

my code is as follows
Api controller program file

```
using BL;
using DAL;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PokerContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
        .GetConnectionString("PokerConnex"))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

builder.Services.AddScoped<Logic>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
public partial class Program { }
```

Context file

```
public  class PokerContext: DbContext
    {
        public PokerContext()
        {

        }

        public PokerContext(DbContextOptions<PokerContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

        //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        //{
        //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        //        "Data Source= (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=PokerAppData")
        //        .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information)
        //        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        //}

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<PokerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source= (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=PokerTestAppData"));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

Logic file (created a parameterless constructor here

```
public class Logic
    {
        Repository _repo;

        public Logic()
        {
            _repo = new Repository();
        }

        public Logic(Repository repo)
        {

            _repo = repo;
        }
}
```

Yet when i try to run the api in browser i always get the same error
any pointers?

Comment: You didn't post where the context is getting injected or created

Answer (score 0):

hmmm okay, uncommenting the Onconfiguring, and adding an if check for isconfigured fixed it

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    $"Data Source= (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog={appCatalog}")
                    .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information)
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
        }
```